# Kafka - Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kerberos

I'm having some troubles with a simple Kafka consumer program:

```
18/06/04 18:13:49 ERROR /log/log.txt: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:647)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:542)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:524)
        at com.carrefour.entequadratura.KafkaHandler.createConsumer(KafkaHandler.java:96)
        at com.carrefour.entequadratura.KafkaHandler.runConsumer(KafkaHandler.java:104)
        at com.carrefour.entequadratura.Main.main(Main.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:577)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.Login.login(Login.java:295)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.Login.<init>(Login.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:44)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:85)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:55)
        ... 17 more
```

These are my properties:

```
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:6667
GROUP_ID=EnteLoader
AUTO_COMMIT=false
AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL=10000
SESSION_TIMEOUT=30000
MAX_POLL_RECORDS=5
KEY_DESERIALIZER=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
VALUE_DESERIALIZER=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT
SASL_MECHANISM=GSSAPI
SASL_KERBEROS_SERVICE_NAME=kafka
```

I read about this could be a possible problem related to jaas.conf but I'm new into Kafka and I don't know how to find it..

Could you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: If you want authorization and authentication in your cluster, take a look at this article: https://developer.ibm.com/code/howtos/kafka-authn-authz.

Comment: _"System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set"_ > if I were you, I would search the Kafka documentation about that Java property.

Comment: @walzer91 - I answered one question on Kafka consumer on kerberised clusters. Here is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744660/kafka-console-consumer-with-kerberos-authentication/49140414#49140414. Step 1 mentioned on this post is what you might need. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Try `export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${PWD}/jaas.conf"` environment var magic.

Answer (score 18):

There are 2 ways you can pass jaas conf to your kafka consumer.

1. If you are using kafka-client version greater than 0.10.2.1 you can set a property `sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD";`
2. As your error message says you can set system property `java.security.auth.login.config`, For this you need to put your jaas config string to a file and give that path as value for above system property.

### jaas.conf

```
KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
serviceName="yourServiceName"
username="userName"
password="password";
};
```

Then set the environment variable:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","/path/to/jaas.conf");
```

I would recommend 1st option since I have faced some issues when I went with the 2nd option.

Comment: you can set it in the props that you are using to create `KafkaConsumer` instance with. Same will be applicable for `KafkaProducer` instance too. 

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("sasl.jaas.config", "/path/to/file");
KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
```

Comment: what is the service name here? I am using a connector but giving "kafkaconnect" as service name didn't work

Comment: tried both not working for me, any suggest?

Comment: What if I set sasl.jaas.config and I still get the error? I am using  confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:7.0.6

Answer (score 1):

Check your application.properties if it is set to
kafka.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

then JAAS Authentication required to set in your property.
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","/File_Location/jaas.conf");

If you are testing your local with authentication. Set Authentication Protocol as Plain_text as

kafka.security.protocol=**PLAINTEXT**

Its tested code. Working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when using spring-kafka  (spring-boot version: `3.0.2`, spring-cloud version: `2022.0.1`).  `export`-ing `KAFKA_USERNAME` and `KAFKA_PASSWORD` in the environment and setting properties below in spring-boot's `application.yml` worked for me.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='${KAFKA_USERNAME}' password='${KAFKA_PASSWORD}';
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
```

Comment: Weird.  So, instead of having it as spring.kafka.producer.properties.sasl.jaas.config and spring.kafka.consumer.properties.sasl.jaas.config, we have one at spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config and one at spring.kafka.consumer.properties.sasl.jaas.config?  I wonder if spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config is just for the producer?  I guess I'll find out shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to connect to a remote Kafka broker from my local and faced the same error.

Official Kafka docs say the same as the above answers https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_jaas_client. However, I'm unsuccessful with `sasl.jaas.config` hence used the static.

Few things to note:

1. The `jaas.conf` content depends on the `sasl.mechanism`.
2. Remove the "\"(backward slash) from each new line, for example

```bash
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="alice" \
    password="alice-secret";
```

becomes

```bash
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="alice"
    password="alice-secret";
};
```

Refer official doc for the right jaas.conf: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_client_staticjaas