# Kafka Username password authentication Issue

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Apache kafka version 2. I am trying to implement authentication for Kafka using Username and password(SASL_PLAINTEXT).I am following below link to implement the same.

https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2017/04/10/kafka-security-mechanism-saslplain/

I have changed the configuration based on above url. But I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaServer' or 'sasl_plaintext.KafkaServer' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/config/kafka_jaas.conf
```

Comment: You can use following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684956/kafka-could-not-find-a-kafkaclient-entry-in-the-jaas-configuration-java

Answer (score 1):

Try to export kafka_opts. 
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/config/kafka_jaas.conf"

Comment: What's the content of the file?