# how to connect siddhi app to remote kafka server using username password

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, kafka-consumer-api, siddhi

i am working on a siddhi app where i have to connect to confluent kafka server. So for that i have to pass username/password in `optional.configuration` right. I am passing it in `@source` (shown below) but getting error `Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set`

**code:**

```
@source(type='kafka',
        topic.list='siddhi-test-topic',
        partition.no.list='0,1',
        threading.option='single.thread',
        group.id='siddhiGroupId',
        bootstrap.servers='abc.confluent.cloud:9092',
optional.configuration="security.protocol:SASL_SSL,ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm:https,
sasl.mechanism:PLAIN,sasl.jaas.config:org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
 required username=XXX password=YYY",
        @map(type='json', @attributes(name="name",amount="amount")))
define stream SweetProductionStream(name string, amount double);
```

**error**:

```
[2020-08-07 03:39:49,461]  INFO {org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig} - ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [abc.confluent.cloud:9092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = true
    sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = 
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    group.id = siddhiGroupId
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
[2020-08-07 03:39:49,465] ERROR {io.siddhi.core.stream.input.source.Source} - Error on 'kafka-test2'. Error when initiating connection with Kafka server: abc.confluent.cloud:9092 in Siddhi App: kafka-test2 Error while connecting at Source 'kafka' at 'SweetProductionStream'. Will retry in '2 min'. io.siddhi.core.exception.ConnectionUnavailableException: Error when initiating connection with Kafka server: abc.confluent.cloud:9092 in Siddhi App: kafka-test2
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.kafka.source.KafkaSource.connect(KafkaSource.java:283)
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.kafka.source.KafkaSource.connect(KafkaSource.java:56)
    at io.siddhi.core.stream.input.source.Source.connectWithRetry(Source.java:160)
    at io.siddhi.core.stream.input.source.Source$1.run(Source.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:702)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:587)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:569)
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.kafka.source.KafkaConsumerThread.<init>(KafkaConsumerThread.java:71)
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.kafka.source.ConsumerKafkaGroup.<init>(ConsumerKafkaGroup.java:57)
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.kafka.source.KafkaSource.connect(KafkaSource.java:261)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:70)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:623)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:46)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:78)
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52341721/4027644), you have to add all the auth configurations in a conf file(JAAS) and cnfigure the conf path for 'java.security.auth.login.config' optional param.

Comment: yes, i have tried passing JAAS config in `java.security.auth.login.config`. Still doesnt work

Comment: Could you remove properties after `sasl.jaas.config` in the annotation and try again? If it doesn't work, let us know the version of the io-kafka extension you are using